# java swing manual start an event without user input

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionevent

I want to activate an event without clicking all the button interface.
ex. when i click button_0, it will print red, and at the same time it will perform action on button_1 and button_2, hence will also print blue and green at the same time.

Those three operation must be separate, solution as merging both action is not applicable on my case, I only made the example as a small guide.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getSource()==button_0)
    {
       System.out.println("red");
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==button_1)
    {   
        System.out.println("blue");
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==button_2)
    {
        System.out.println("green");
    }
}
```

Comment: The correct way to do it: create one method for each action ( e.g. `printRed()`, `printBlue()` and `printGreen()`) then inside your `actionPerformed()` call those methods. Then you can also easily call those methods from outside a Swing event.

Comment: You could also use [JButton#fireActionPerformed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#fireActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dirty way to do it:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getSource()==button_0)
    {
       System.out.println("red");
       button_1.doClick();
       button_2.doClick();
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==button_1)
    {   
        System.out.println("blue");
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==button_2)
    {
        System.out.println("green");
    }
}
```

Comment: how about for jcombobox?

Comment: @Jeric example?